# Is there a way to play pygame.mixer.Sound only for the duration of time a circuit is broken?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, raspberry-pi3

I'm building a set of musical stairs with motion sensors and a raspberry pi and am quite new to python. Currently when the user goes passes a motion sensor a note will play for the full duration of the .wav file but I was wondering is there a way that a sound will only play for the length of time the motion sensor is passed?

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import pygame.mixer
 pygame.mixer.init()

 '''GPIO setup'''
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarningS(False)

'''Define stairs and GPIO pins'''
step1 = 4
step2 = 17
step3 = 27

'''Motion sensor setup'''
GPIO.setup(step1, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(step2, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(step3, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)

'''Sound files'''
C1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/C1.wav")
D = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/D.wav")
E = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/E.wav")

def play(pin):
    sound = sound_pins[pin]
    sound.play()

'''Dictionary  of steps and sounds'''
sound_pins  = {
    step1: C1,
    step2: D,
    step3: E,
    }

for pin in sound_pins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.add_even_detect(pin, GPIO.RISING, play, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for `GPIO.BOTH`. When this is triggered, check if this is a rising or falling edge with `input` and then call `play()` or `stop()` accordingly.

Something like this, you'll get the idea:

```
def play(pin):
    sound = sound_pins[pin]
    if GPIO.input(pin):
        sound.play()
    else:
        sound.stop()

for pin in sound_pins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.add_even_detect(pin, GPIO.BOTH, play, 100)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. When I tried that I was met with "RunTime Error: Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel". The sound objects are already stored in a dictionary mapped against their corresponding GPIO pin. What would I store them against in the sounds dictionary?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the second dict is not necessary. I used GPIO once a long time ago, so IIRC you have to add a single GPIO.BOTH handler instead of a RAISING and a FALLING handler. But still the key message is: call `stop()` on the sounds objects if they should no longer be played.